# Для поставщика ADO.NET с неизменяемым именем "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, odp.net

Доброго, столкнулся с ошибкой:
Для поставщика ADO.NET с неизменяемым именем "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" не найден поставщик Entity Framework. Убедитесь, что поставщик зарегистрирован в разделе "entityFramework" файла конфигурации приложения.

при выполнении:

```
 using (var db = new DataAccessLayer.Entities())
        {
            var response = db.DOCUMENTS.Where(d => d.TYPE_DOCUMENT == TYPE_DOCUMENT).ToList();
```

В конфигах приложений

```
 <configSections>
<!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
<section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
```

```
 <system.data>
<DbProviderFactories>
  <clear />
  <add name="Oracle Data Provider for .NET" invariant="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET" type="Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
  <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
</DbProviderFactories>
```

Проверил и уровнял все версии EF и ODP, но результат остается неизменным.
Что я мог упустить или сделал не так?
Заранее спасибо за помощь

Comment: А сборка лежит  Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.DLL лежит в папке провайдеров? (рядом с Oracle.DataAccess.DLL)

Comment: перепроверил. да, присутствуют

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение было найдено. Перевел приложение на .NET Framework 4.5. Удалил Oracle.DataAccess и оставил Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.